# Long running tasks in aspx page on Sharepoint 2010 shows "Page cannot be displayed" in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have a long running process n the aspx page deployed in Sharepoint 2010. Assume that the process is Thread.Sleep(10 minutes)  and logs that the process completes successfully in EventViewer.

Deploying the code in Domain A and B servers, things run fine. But after deploying the code in Domain C SharePoint server, then pages displays "Page cannot be displayed" in browser exactacly after two minutes.

Attaching HTTPWatch/Fiddler shows connection reset by server. Checking the IIS logs shows that the Connection was aborted/terminated.

Strange thing is the the server process gets completed even if the client sees the above error. The server log says that long running process completed.

Could this be a network issue? Firewall issue or Sharepoint 2010 server issue? We tried changing execution timeout in Templates\Layouts\web.config file but still no use. changed timeout values for AppPool account in IIS. Change the KeepConnectionAlive settings for the browsers. Nothing seems to work.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you check MOSS logs?

Comment: Are you using VM servers? If so should be easier to handle registry setting differences by rolling back to base image on problem server...

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with incorrect DNS/proxy settings, AlternateMapping settings in MOSS Central Administration.